# Downloading binary files in Node with Fetch-node.buffer() - file wasn't properly decoded

Tags: node.js, file-transfer

Important update: I found that **I don't have such an issue on Apple Mac! Only on Windows 7**!

[image]

The same pdf file was downloaded twice. One file I can open, second one - I can't open. Maybe somebody can give me any advice or know solution? Thank you!

[image]

I use fetch-node library to download binary files in Electron.js. When files are small there is no issues but with large files I see periodically (not constantly) the issue with file decoding. I can't open such files! Also I found some files have 5KB size but should have 10Mb+ size!

```
function fastFetch(url, dest, fileName, callback) {
  console.log("fastFetch-------------------------------------------------------");

  //import fetch from 'node-fetch';
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.buffer())
    .then(buffer => {

      const settings = {
        flags: 'w',
        encoding: null, //not applicable / no changes
        mode: 0o666
      };

      try {
        fs.writeFileSync(dest, buffer, settings);

        let msgOK = {
          filename: fileName,
          status: 'OK',
          text: `File downloaded successfully`
        }
        if (callback) callback(msgOK);
        console.log(msgOK.text);
        isLoading = false; //IMPORTANT! 

      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.stack || err.message);

        let msgErr = {
          filename: fileName,
          status: 'ERROR',
          text: `Error in file downloading ${err.message}`
        }
        ERRORS.push(err);
        if (callback) callback(msgErr);
      }

    })
}
```

Version with WriteStream - the same issue - one file can be open, another one can't be open due to encoding issue:

```
function fetchWithFIleStream(url, dest, fileName, callback) {
  console.log("fetch With FIle Stream-------------------------------------------------------");
  //import fetch from 'node-fetch';
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
      console.log("--------------------------------------------")
      //console.log(res);
      console.log(res.ok);
      console.log(res.status);
      console.log(res.statusText);
      console.log(res.headers.raw());
      console.log(res.headers.get('content-type'));
      console.log("--------------------------------------------")
      //ERROR: Not a function: res.setEncoding('binary');
      return res.buffer();
    })
    .then(buffer => {

      const settings = {
        flags: 'w',
        encoding: null, //default: 'utf8',
        fd: null,
        mode: 0o666,
        autoClose: true
      };

      // response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest, settings));
      var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(dest, settings);
      wstream.write(buffer);

      wstream.on('finish', function () {
        //console.log('END------------------------------------------------------')
        let msgOK = {
          filename: fileName,
          status: 'OK',
          text: `File downloaded successfully`
        }

        if (callback) callback(msgOK);
        console.log(msgOK.text);
        isLoading = false; //IMPORTANT!

        wstream.end();

      });

      wstream.end();

    })
}
```